# Optional character in Regex lookbehind (JS)

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to use Regex to parse some content from a template. There are opening tags, and closing tags, but I just want to select the content between these tags (so that I can String.replace)

The content looks something like this:

```
OpenTag
  The Content I want
CloseTag

OpenTag The Content I want CloseTag
```

and the regex I'm using looks like this:

```
/(?<=OpenTag(\n))(.*?)(?=CloseTag)/msg
```

The problem I'm having is that sometimes there might be a newline, and other times not, but as soon as I make the newline optional in the lookbehind via `(\n)?`, the newline gets included in the capture group (even though it seems like it should be part of the look behind).

If I un-optional the newline, then I don't get a match on the second example in content.

Example on regex101.com, https://regex101.com/r/teBEQ9/2

Comment: JS doesn't support positive lookbehinds.

Comment: isn't it a positive lookbehind because I want to match where the `OpenTag` (and optionally a newline) precedes the match? as opposed to matching where the match is _not_ preceded

Comment: I don't think you need lookaheads or lookbehinds here, just start your regex with `OpenTag` and end it with `CloseTag` and capture the middle of it

Comment: @AndyRay I think the part I'm missing is how to selectively capture only the middle of it for use with String.replace? without the lookarounds it seems like the OpenTag and CloseTag would also get replaced when I run String.replace

Comment: Sorry, JS doesnt support any lookbehinds.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I think ES2018 might have support for them? When I run the regex in my JS code (processed via babel) I get a match, it just includes the newline, so it seems like the lookarounds must be working

Comment: If you don't need it supported in web browsers then go for it. Regex101 is clearly showing you that it doesn't work in whatever browser you are using since it should be tapping into your browser's engine when the JS flavor is chosen.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It's running in Chrome for me, I assumed babel was transpiling it down to something that would work in other browsers too, but I havn't tested. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_lookbehind_assertion

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thanks, that explains why it was working in Chrome, glad you mentioned it, I'll switch up my approach to one similar to your answer

Comment: Glad I could help. I use Firefox and it failed so I didn't bother checking in Chrome so we're both right, hah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
OpenTag\s*([^]*?)\s*CloseTag
```

And your desired text will be in `$1`

https://regex101.com/r/FRbTKb/2

Answer (score 2):

The dot in with the `s` flag matches the `\n` character as well, and since it's optional it's captured. Use `Array.match()` and trim the results:

```js
const str = `OpenTag
  The Content I want
CloseTag

OpenTag The Content I want CloseTag`

const result = str.match(/(?<=OpenTag)(.*?)(?=CloseTag)/msg).map(s => s.trim())

console.log(result)
```

Comment: TY for the response, so it sounds like optional in this case means "allow but dont include in lookbehind", where I was hoping it meant "include in lookbehind if exists". Seems like maybe theres no way to write a lookbehind that amounts to "capture match precluded by "foo" or "foo\n", and at the same time also keep the "\n" out of the capture group.

Comment: Matches are greedy. In some cases you can tell them to be lazy - `.*?` for example, but not in this case.